# Count of each day of the week between May 01, 2020 and April 30, 2021 in SQL(BigQuery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to calculate the total number of occurrences of each day of the week ( # of Sundays, # of Mondays, etc) for the period May 1, 2020 thru April 30, 2021 in SQL(BigQuery).

I have the following relevant fields to work with:

| Field | Type |
| --- | --- |
| started_at_cst | DATETIME |
| ended_at_cst | DATETIME |
| Day_of_Week | STRING |

The beginning date for the period will be the earliest date from started_at_cst and the ending date will be the latest date from ended_at_cst.

Comment: What do you want the results to look like?  Is the data coming in multiple rows?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should create a daily record of the period that you want to create the report.
For that, you can create a table as 'calendar table'.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CalendarTable
    (
    Date datetime NOT NULL,
    DayWeekNumber nvarchar(50) NULL
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.CalendarTable ADD CONSTRAINT
    PK_CalendarTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    Date
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
Go
```

After that you should fill calendar table like this:

```
Truncate Table CalendarTable
Declare @FromDate as datetime , @ToDate as datetime, @counter as int , @DateRecord as int,
@Date as Datetime

Set @FromDate = '2020-03-21'
Set @ToDate = '2021-03-21'
Set @Counter = 1

Set @DateRecord = dateDiff(D,@FromDate, @ToDate)

While (@Counter <=@DateRecord)
BEGIN
Insert Into CalendarTable (Date,DayWeekNumber)
    Select DateAdd(d,@Counter,@FromDate),DATEPART(dw,DateAdd(d,@Counter,@FromDate))
Set @Counter += 1

END
```

At the end join it with your occurrence table

```
Select Date,(Select Count(*) From occurrencesTable Where started_at_cst>= CalendarTable.Date
and ended_at_cst<= CalendarTable.Date ) as NumberOfOccurence from CalendarTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you desire thanks to the `GENERATE_ARRAY` function:

```
WITH dow_generated AS (
    # Step 2. Extract the day of the week for each generated date
    SELECT
        FORMAT_DATE("%A",dates) AS day_of_week
    FROM (
            # Step 1. Generate an array of dates from minimum of started_at_cst to maximumn of ended_at_cst
            SELECT 
                GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(MIN(started_at_cst), MAX(ended_at_cst)) as dates
            FROM `your_table`) dates_generated, unnest(dates_generated.dates) dates)

# Step 3. Count the different days of the week
SELECT day_of_week, COUNT(day_of_week) AS day_count
FROM dow_generated
GROUP BY day_of_week
```

You should obtain a table like this one:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want the results in the format you specified.  If so, this should do what you want:

```
WITH t AS (
       select datetime('2020-05-01') as started_at_cst, datetime('2021-05-30') as ended_at_cst
)
SELECT FORMAT_DATE('%A', dte) AS day_of_week, COUNT(*) AS day_count
FROM (SELECT MIN(started_at_cst) as min_started_at_cst, MAX(ended_at_cst) as max_ended_at_cst
      FROM t
     ) t CROSS JOIN
     UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE(min_started_at_cst), DATE(max_ended_at_cst), INTERVAL 1 day)) dte
GROUP BY day_of_week
ORDER BY MIN(dte)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
select format_date('%A', day) day_of_the_week, count(1) days_count 
from `project.dataset.table`,
unnest(generate_date_array(date(started_at_cst), date(ended_at_cst))) day
where day between '2020-05-01' and '2021-04-30'
group by day_of_the_week
```

in case if you want output to be sorted by weekday - add below `order by`

```
order by case day_of_the_week
  when 'Monday' then 1
  when 'Tuesday' then 2
  when 'Wednesday' then 3
  when 'Thursday' then 4
  when 'Friday' then 5
  when 'Saturday' then 6
  when 'Sunday' then 7
end
```

Finally - if above order by looks too wordy for you - use below version

```
select day_of_the_week, count(1) days_count , pos
from (
  select format_date('%A', day) day_of_the_week, format_date('%u', day) pos
  from `project.dataset.table`,
  unnest(generate_date_array(date(started_at_cst), date(ended_at_cst))) day
  where day between '2020-05-01' and '2021-04-30'
)  
group by day_of_the_week, pos
order by pos
```